# Laravel JWT tokens are Invalid after refresh them in a authentication JWT approach

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, laravel, jwt

**EDIT:**

Read the discussion about the bug at: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/83

**MY ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I'm implement with [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) my protected resources that require an authenticated user with bellow code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['before' => 'jwt.auth', 'after' => 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
    // Protected routes
});
```

When user 'sign in' on API an Authorization token is created, and sent on response Authorization header to client application that call the resource. So, client applications when intercept a Authorization token on header of any response, set a variable/session/whatever with this token value, to send again to API on next request.

The first request for a protected resource after 'login' works fine, but the next client application request to API with a refreshed token, gives the following error (API mount all responses in json format):

```
{
    "error": "token_invalid"
}
```

What can be happen with refreshed tokens? My refresh token implementation (set as a after middleware) is wrong? Or isn't necessary to manually refresh all Authorization token that come with client apps requests?

**UPDATE:**

I update the jwt-auth RefreshToken middleware as propose [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/pull/78), but the `token_invalid` persist.

**BUG:**

I guess that I found what happens. Note that in the refresh method, old token is added to blacklist cache case enabled:

```
// Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTManager
public function refresh(Token $token)
{
    $payload = $this->decode($token);

    if ($this->blacklistEnabled) {
        // invalidate old token
        $this->blacklist->add($payload);
    }

    // return the new token
    return $this->encode(
        $this->payloadFactory->setRefreshFlow()->make([
            'sub' => $payload['sub'],
            'iat' => $payload['iat']
        ])
    );
}
```

And note that in add to blacklist method the key is the jti param from old token payload:

```
// Tymon\JWTAuth\Blacklist
public function add(Payload $payload)
{
    $exp = Utils::timestamp($payload['exp']);

    // there is no need to add the token to the blacklist
    // if the token has already expired
    if ($exp->isPast()) {
        return false;
    }

    // add a minute to abate potential overlap
    $minutes = $exp->diffInMinutes(Utils::now()->subMinute());

    $this->storage->add($payload['jti'], [], $minutes);

    return true;
}
```

Thus, when has on blacklist method is called, the old token jti param is the same that the new, so the new token is in blacklist:

```
// Tymon\JWTAuth\Blacklist
public function has(Payload $payload)
{
    return $this->storage->has($payload['jti']);
}
```

If you don't need the blacklist functionality just set to false on jwt.php configuration file. But I can't say if it expose to some security vulnerability.

Read the discussion about the bug at: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/83

Comment: Has your issue been solved in new version 0.5.3 ? As mentioned by the author, it has been solved in the latest version. But I still having same issue like yours.

Comment: @davidcoder when I found this issue, I write a wrapper to jwt-auth to solve it, because I needed a fast solution. Basically I overwrite the RefreshToken middleware in my App\Http\Middleware package. But I will test the new version to verify what's happen.

Comment: I can tell the issue is still on. 
Thank you very much for this insight. Disabling blacklisting worked

Comment: i want every request should have token even form differnt controller, how can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I get this issue, the solution that I found to get my project working was to generate a new token with data from older token on each new request.

My solution, that works for me, is bad, ugly, and can generate more issues if you have many async requests and your API(or business core) server is slow.

For now is working, but I will investigate more this issue, cause after 0.5.3 version the issue continues.

E.g:

Request 1 (GET /login):

```
Some guest data on token
```

Request 2 (POST /login response):

```
User data merged with guest data on old token generating a new token
```

Procedural code example(you can do better =) ), you can run this on routes.php out of routes, I say that is ugly haha:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// AUTH TOKEN WORK
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
$authToken = null;
$getAuthToken = function() use ($authToken, $Response) {
    if($authToken === null) {
         $authToken = JWTAuth::parseToken();
    }
    return $authToken;
};

$getLoggedUser = function() use ($getAuthToken) {
    return $getAuthToken()->authenticate();
};

$getAuthPayload = function() use ($getAuthToken) {
    try {
        return $getAuthToken()->getPayload();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return [];
    }
};

$mountAuthPayload = function($customPayload) use ($getLoggedUser, $getAuthPayload) {
    $currentPayload = [];
    try {
        $currentAuthPayload = $getAuthPayload();
        if(count($currentAuthPayload)) {
            $currentPayload = $currentAuthPayload->toArray();
        }
        try {
            if($user = $getLoggedUser()) {
                $currentPayload['user'] = $user;
            }
            $currentPayload['isGuest'] = false;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // is guest
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        // Impossible to parse token
    }

    foreach ($customPayload as $key => $value) {
        $currentPayload[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $currentPayload;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// AUTH TOKEN PAYLOAD
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
try {
    $getLoggedUser();
    $payload = ['isGuest' => false];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $payload = ['isGuest' => true];
}

try {
    $payload = $mountAuthPayload($payload);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Make nothing cause token is invalid, expired, etc., or not exists.
    // Like a guest session. Create a token without user data.
}
```

Some route(simple example to save user mobile device):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['before' => 'jwt.auth', 'after' => 'jwt.refresh']], function () use ($getLoggedUser, $mountAuthPayload) {
    Route::post('/session/device', function () use ($Response, $getLoggedUser, $mountAuthPayload) {
        $Response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response();
        $user = $getLoggedUser();

        // code to save on database the user device from current "session"...

        $payload = app('tymon.jwt.payload.factory')->make($mountAuthPayload(['device' => $user->device->last()->toArray()]));
        $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
        $Response->header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);

        $responseContent = ['setted' => 'true'];

        $Response->setContent($responseContent);
        return $Response;
    });
});
```

Comment: i want every request should have token even form differnt controller, how can i do it?