# JWT in laravel lumen

Tags: laravel, jwt, lumen

I ran into the JWT bug of Laravel (I use Lumen) ([Laravel JWT tokens are Invalid after refresh them in a authentication JWT approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703260/laravel-jwt-tokens-are-invalid-after-refresh-them-in-a-authentication-jwt-approa))

I saw that the post above contains a workaround, but I wonder if someone knows how to correct the code of plugin. I know that this only is a temporary solution since it will be overwritten if I update the package.

Thanks